# Linq to XML to populate parent/child relationship

Tags: c#, lambda, linq-to-xml

I would like to populate a two objects that have a parent child relationship. The two objects are `Payment` and `Invoice`. Each `Payment` may apply to multiple `Invoice` objects as a customer may write a single payment to cover multiple invoices.

```
class Payment
{
    public string PaymentId {get; set;}
    public decimal PaymentAmount {get; set;}
    public List<Invoice> InvoiceCollection {get; set;} // Collection of Invoices
}

class Invoice
{
    public string InvoiceId {get; set;}
    public decimal InvoiceAmount {get; set;}
    public DateTime InvoiceDate {get; set;}
}
```

I would like to use LINQ to XML with Lambda syntax to get the XML data into the objects. The problem I am running into is that the API call that gets the information return multiple payments. I could make a single API call for each payment however, that would be inefficient when I can make a single API call passing in all of my payment IDs and get back all the data. Problem is I am confused on how to parse it such that I get back a collection of Payment objects. Is it possible or will I need to make separate API calls for each payment?

```
<payment>
...
</payment>
<payment>
    <paymentId>7400</paymentId>
    <paymentAmount>540</paymentAmount>
    <paymentDate>05/22/2018</paymentDate>
    <invoice>
        <invoiceId>KADS333</invoiceId>
        <invoiceAmount>175</invoiceAmount>
        <invoiceDate>4/27/2018</invoiceDate>
    </invoice>
    <invoice>
        <invoiceId>53222</invoiceId>
        <invoiceAmount>300</invoiceAmount>
        <invoiceDate>4/04/2018</invoiceDate>
    </invoice>
    <invoice>
        <invoiceId>KAZO111</invoiceId>
        <invoiceAmount>65</invoiceAmount>
        <invoiceDate>3/12/2018</invoiceDate>
    </invoice>
</payment>
<payment>
...
</payment>
```

Also ... I need to be able to filter out any invoices that don't have the letter `K` in the `InvoiceId`. For example `53222`. (These are airport codes and the `K` is always present in the airport code.)

Here is the Linq I started with but I am having problems populating the `PaymenModel` and also the `InvoiceModel` which is a property of the `PaymentModel`.

```
List<PaymentModel> paymentDetails = xml.Descendants("payment")
        .Where(
            d => d.Element("invoiceId").Value.Contains("K")
        )
        .Select(x => new Invoice
        {
            InvoiceId = x.Element("invoiceId").Value.ToString(),
            InvoiceAmount = (decimal)x.Element("invoiceAmount"),
            InvoiceDate = (DateTime)x.Element("invoiceDate")
        }).ToList<InvoiceModel>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the requirements correctly, the following code should produce the wanted result:

```
List<Payment> paymentDetails = xml.Descendants("payment")
        .Select(x => new Payment()
        {
            PaymentId = x.Element("paymentId").Value,
            PaymentAmount = (decimal)x.Element("paymentAmount"),
            InvoiceCollection = x.Elements("invoice")
                .Where(i => i.Element("invoiceId").Value.Contains("K"))
                .Select(i => new Invoice()
                {
                    InvoiceId = i.Element("invoiceId").Value.ToString(),
                    InvoiceAmount = (decimal)i.Element("invoiceAmount"),
                    InvoiceDate = (DateTime)i.Element("invoiceDate")
                }).ToList()
        }).ToList();
```

It creates a list of all payments, which will contain properties like `PaymentId` and `InvoiceCollection`, which holds the invoices where the `InvoiceId` contains a `"K"`.

Comment: How could I adjust this if I only wanted payments that had invoices that contains a `"K"`. Currently it returns ALL payments.

Comment: To achive this, just add `.Where(x => x.Elements("invoice").Elements("invoiceId").Any(y => y.Value.Contains("K")))` after `xml.Descendants("payment")`.